# get the next element with a specific class after a specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, traversal

I have a HTML markup like this:

```
<p>
  <label>Arrive</label>
  <input id="from-date1" class="from-date calender" type="text" />
</p>

<p>
  <label>Depart</label>
  <input id="to-date1" class="to-date calender" type="text" />
</p>

<p>
  <label>Arrive</label>
  <input id="from-date2" class="from-date calender" type="text" />
</p>

<p>
  <label>Depart</label>
  <input id="to-date2" class="to-date calender" type="text" />
</p>
```

I want to get the next element after from dates to get the corresponding to date. (Layout is a little more complex but from date has from-date class and to date has to-date class).

This is I am trying to do, I want to take a from date element and find the next element in the dom with to-date class. I tried this:

```
$('#from-date1').next('.to-date')
```

but it is giving me empty jQuery element. I think this is because `next` gives the next sibling matching the selector. How can I get the corresponding `to-date`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Couldn't find a direct way of doing this, so wrote a little recursive algorithm for this.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/sHGDP/

`nextInDOM()` function takes 2 arguments namely the element to start looking from and the selector to match.

instead of

```
$('#from-date1').next('.to-date')
```

you can use:

```
nextInDOM('.to-date', $('#from-date1'))
```

**Code**

```
function nextInDOM(_selector, _subject) {
    var next = getNext(_subject);
    while(next.length != 0) {
        var found = searchFor(_selector, next);
        if(found != null) return found;
        next = getNext(next);
    }
    return null;
}
function getNext(_subject) {
    if(_subject.next().length > 0) return _subject.next();
    return getNext(_subject.parent());
}
function searchFor(_selector, _subject) {
    if(_subject.is(_selector)) return _subject;
    else {
        var found = null;
        _subject.children().each(function() {
            found = searchFor(_selector, $(this));
            if(found != null) return false;
        });
        return found;
    }
    return null; // will/should never get here
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it did give me the next element. You have made this into a nice little function. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad it worked. :) It was a really cool problem to solve, in fact i think something like `nextInDOM()` will be useful in a lot of places.

Comment: Yes, I used it in my site to make the calender default the to dates to the date a person selects for the from date. Many thanks and I will definitely be using this function for my future projects also.

Answer (score 4):

`.next('.to-date')` does not return anything, because  you have an additional `p` in between

You need `.parent().next().find('.to-date')`.

You might have to adjust this if your dom is more complicated than your example. But essentially it boils down to something like this:

```
$(".from-date").each(function(){
    // for each "from-date" input
    console.log($(this));
    // find the according "to-date" input
    console.log($(this).parent().next().find(".to-date"));
});
```

edit: It's much better and faster to just look for the ID. The following code searches all from-dates and gets the according to-dates:

```
function getDeparture(el){
    var toId = "#to-date"+el.attr("id").replace("from-date","");
    //do something with the value here
    console.log($(toId).val());
}

var id = "#from-date",
    i = 0;

while($(id+(++i)).length){
    getDeparture($(id+i));
}
```

Take a look at the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/pUQyy/1/).

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to get the next item irrespective of the markup, as I have several recurring places for this, and I want to apply this functionality everywhere irrespective of the markup.

Comment: well, this is highly inefficient...just look for the id then! YOu have an id, so use it - this is much faster then traversing the dom with an recursive algorithm. I will edit my answer to show you how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var flag = false;
var requiredElement = null;
$.each($("*"),function(i,obj){
    if(!flag){
        if($(obj).attr("id")=="from-date1"){
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    else{
        if($(obj).hasClass("to-date")){
            requiredElement = obj;
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I didnt try this...but since you are looping over all the elements in the Dom, I believe this might be very inefficient.

Comment: I agree on what you are concerned about. But other forms of traversing will use more of scripting. Further, I don't believe that traversing through whole of DOM will take much of time for this level of searching.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var item_html = document.getElementById('from-date1');
    var str_number = item_html.attributes.getNamedItem("id").value;
    // Get id's value.
    var data_number = showIntFromString(str_number);


    // Get to-date this class
    // Select by JQ. $('.to-date'+data_number)
    console.log('to-date'+data_number);

    function showIntFromString(text){
       var num_g = text.match(/\d+/);
       if(num_g != null){
          console.log("Your number:"+num_g[0]);
          var num = num_g[0];
          return num;
       }else{
          return;
       }
    }
```

Use JS. to get the key number from your id. Analysis it than output the number. Use JQ. selecter combine string with you want than + this number. Hope this can help you too.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I figured I'd add a jQuery free alternate solution :)

I tried to keep the code simple by avoiding traversing the DOM.

```
let inputArray = document.querySelectorAll(".calender");

function nextInput(currentInput, inputClass) {
    for (i = 0; i < inputArray.length - 1; i++) {
        if(currentInput == inputArray[i]) {
            for (j = 1; j < inputArray.length - i; j++) {
                //Check if the next element exists and if it has the desired class
                if(inputArray[i + j] && (inputArray[i + j].className == inputClass)) {
                    return inputArray[i + j];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}

let currentInput = document.getElementById('from-date1');

console.log(nextInput(currentInput, 'to-date calender'));
```

If you know that the to date will always be the next input element with a class of "calender", then you don't need the second loop.