# jquery traversing table

Tags: jquery, jquery-traversing

When i click on a link  "zmeniť pozíciu", i want to save its closest img to variable.

```
<table border="1">
    <tbody> 
        <tr>        
            <th rowspan="3">1</th>
            <th>Nadpis</th>
            <td colspan="9">Eiusmod tempor</td>
            <td> <a href="#">zmeniť</a> </td>
            <td rowspan="3"> <a class="zmenit-poziciu" href="#">zmeniť pozíciu</a> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Text</th>
            <td colspan="9">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam ...
            </td>
            <td> <a href="#">zmeniť</a> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="obrazok">
            <th>Obrázok</th>
            <td colspan="9"> <img alt="img" src="http://lorempixel.com/500/120/sports/1"> </td>
            <td ><a href="#">zmeniť</a></td>

        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

i tried this but it doesn't work

```
$(".zmenit-poziciu").click(function() {

        var img = $(this).parent().closest("obrazok").html();
        alert(img);
        return false
    });
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XCxjX/6/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the image like this

```
$(".zmenit-poziciu").click(function () {
  var img = $(this)
            .closest('tr') // get to the tr level
            .nextAll(".obrazok:first") // find the next tr sibling with class=obrazok
            .find('img'); // find the img
  alert(img.attr('src'));
  return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/Z5CeE/

Answer (score 0):

Wrong selector used.

Change:-

```
var img = $(this).parent().closest("obrazok").html();
```

To:-

```
var img = $(this).parent().closest(".obrazok").html();
```

Using your current selector, you are actually looking for a tag called obrazok, which I'm guessing you don't have in your doc.

Comment: Can I ask why you're using (perpetuating the use of) `parent()` *and* `closest()`?

Comment: parent will only get you to the `td` level

Comment: @DavidThomas are parent and closest things we should avoid now?

Comment: Sure, I was responding to the user's specific question.

Comment: @gbtimmon: no, not to be *avaoided*, but `parent()` goes up one level (to the parent), and then `closest()` looks among the ancestor elements for the first occurence of an element that matches the selector. So, `parent()` just seemed redundant in context, so I wondered if there was an explicit reason for using it is all.

Answer (score 0):

Closest gets you the *closest element matching the selector higher up the hierarchy*. [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

From the docs:

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the
>   selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its
>   ancestors in the DOM tree.

In your case, the `tr` matching `.obrazok` is not higher in the hierarchy when viewed from the clicked link.

You will need something that traverses the DOM and gets you the nearest element in the DOM. This answer I posted for another question I believe should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12873187/921204

You can use it like:

```
$(".zmenit-poziciu").click(function() {
    var img = nextInDOM('.obrazok', $(this));
    alert(img);
    return false
});
```