# When element clicked, find closest element relative to this element with another class and toggle it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am missing something here. When the row with the class `one` is clicked, I want to find only the *closest* row with the class `two` and then toggle (show/hide) it.

```js
$(".one").on('click', function() {
   $(this).find('.two').toggle(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr class="one">
        <td> Hello </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td> world </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="two">
        <td> Foo </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="two">
        <td> Bar </td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

Comment: if it is peer to your clickable element you can use `.siblings()` instead of `.find()` https://api.jquery.com/siblings/ - or a different method like `parents` or `closest` or `next` depending on what you want. https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$(".one").on('click', function() {
    $(this).nextAll('.two:first').toggle(); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/5ossufmj/

Comment: Your solution works immediately for this case. But what I am trying to apply it to: I want to get the next element with that `two` class relative to the position of the element I clicked. When I apply your answer, It always returns the first element with class of `two`, ignoring the position of the element I clicked.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Neil By "position" do you mean the position in your code or its actual position on the screen?

Comment: The next `<tr></tr>` element with the class of `two` relative to the element I clicked. I'm not sure what you mean by position of code or screen. I think screen, because I am using bootstrap for responsive design, so screen may change.

Comment: @Neil I see. This is probably what you wanted, [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/5ossufmj/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want `.next()`. It finds the next sibling in the DOM respecting placement in the DOM.

https://api.jquery.com/next/

Or maybe this:  [get the next element with a specific class after a specific element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560028/get-the-next-element-with-a-specific-class-after-a-specific-element/11560428#11560428)

**Edit**

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/abalter/4kw4r6sf/) is a working solution:

```
$('.one').on('click', function () {
    var this_el = $(this);
    var el = findNextWithClass(this_el, "two");
    if (el != null)
    {
        el.toggle();
    }
    else
    {
        alert("null");
    }
});

function findNextWithClass(element, className) {
    var next = element.next();
    if (next.hasClass(className)) {
        return next
    } else {
        if (next != null) {
            return findNextWithClass(next, className);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a horrible way of testing classes, and if there's no next sibling with such class, then your code will fail because `null` doesn't have the `.toggle` property...

Comment: I see your point. I need to catch that condition. I put an if then in the click method.

Comment: BTW, why is that a "horrible" way of testing classes. An educational moment for me...

Comment: Let say if the element has two classes, `two item`, then your code will fail silently. You probably want to use `.hasClass` in jQuery instead.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I'll edit the answer again.